# How does Visual Studio 2013 keep track of files to publish using FTP

Tags: ftp, visual-studio-2013

I am publishing to a server in another country so the date/time is very different to my development machine.

So I am hoping it does not:

1. Always publish every file (unlikely)
2. If not 1 then I hope it's more clever than just date/time comparison between PCs.

**Some clarification:**

1. I do not know how does Visual Studio 2013 keeps track of files to publish using FTP.
2. I like to know how VS2013 keeps track of which files to upload or if it even keeps track of such.

Answer (score 0):

For publishing web projects with the FTP or File System methods, VS uses the last write time of the files.  However, these times should be compared relative to UTC, so timezones should not make a difference.  It also uses ~1 second rounding to allow for some time skew between machines.